# Determine Last Modification Datetime for an Azure Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am developing an application which may be hosted on a microsoft sql server, or on Azure SQL, depending upon the end user's wishes.

My whole system works fine with the exception of some WCF functions which determine the last modification time of tables using the following technique:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) as tableName, 
       last_user_update as lastUpdate
FROM mydb.sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
```

This query fails in Azure.  Is there any analogous way to get table last modification dates from Azure's sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try removing the `mydb.` from the query. **4 part notation is not supported in SQL Azure**. You can only work in the context of a single database, so just try executing:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) as tableName, 
       last_user_update as lastUpdate
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
```

Comment: @SilverNinja  Thank you very much for that rapid response.   That worked!

Comment: And thank you @astaykov ,  we are now up and running with Azure.

Comment: according to this post, this method is NOT RELIABLE: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73745/is-information-in-sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-reliable

Comment: If you have better answer post it!